# Timer WPF -the function of timers doesnt work on time

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private DispatcherTimer timer;   // timer  
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);  
        timer.Start();
        int b;//if arrives here instead of the function timer_Tick!!!!!!!
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // function
    }
}
```

The timer function starts only after it finishes the current function.
instead of starting just when the times starts, the function starts after the "int b" line!!

Comment: Was there a question in here? Also, how did you determine this was the case?

Comment: What are you meaning? I have found the problem by break points

Comment: He's asking what is your question. You state a bunch of things but never ask a question.

Comment: How will anything start if you are stuck in a break point?

Comment: My question is: I want the function "timer_tick" to happen as soon as the the timer starts, but it starts only aftet the "int b" line... how can I change it?

Comment: Please read my answer. It's likely what you're looking for

Comment: anyawy- Can I change it  and solve my problem?

Comment: What is it not doing in the overall context?

Comment: It does the "int b" before the function ! I want to change the order

Answer (score 3):

Please read the MSDN for DispatcherTimer, it states explicitly they are added to the Dispatcher Queue.

> The DispatcherTimer is reevaluated at the top of every Dispatcher loop.
>   Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs. This is because DispatcherTimer operations are placed on the Dispatcher queue like other operations. When the DispatcherTimer operation executes is dependent on the other jobs in the queue and their priorities.

[DispatcherTimer MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx)

You might try System.Timers.Timer instead.

[System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried System.Timers.Timer but it happenned there too.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you mean.  If you stepped through this with breakpoints, how do you know start didn't happen before int b?  Do you mean it didn't go to the new method?

Comment: I put my break point in "timer.start" and conticnued---  I have seen that the "int b" happened before the "time tick"-

Comment: Of course it does.  You have a 1 second interval before you are going to enter timer tick.  That's the point of the timer.

Comment: OK... but how can I change it anyway?

Comment: Do you want it to execute once a second, AND immediately after you start the timer?  I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want this order: timerstart, and then the funtion tick and then "int b". is it posible?

Comment: yes, just call timer_Tick(null, null); before int b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82613/discussion-between-user3590450-and-oppassum).

Comment: butt the function is called nly  once